# JSlink changes after creating site from template

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, jslink

I created a site with several lists and several CSR renderers for those lists. I applied the renderers to the forms via JSLink. Then I tried to save the site as template and create another one from this tempalte. All the JS links are now broken and lead nowhere.

Here is one of the JSLinks from the initial site:

```
 <JSLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">~Site/SiteAssets/FormsManagement/Js/utils.js|~Site/SiteAssets/FormsManagement/Js/paymentsFormRenderer.js</JSLink>
</WebPart>
```

And here is what it changed to after the template creation:

```
<JSLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">/sites/home/test-subsite/SiteAssets/FormsManagement/Js/utils.js|/sites/home/test-subsite/SiteAssets/FormsManagement/Js/paymentsFormRenderer.js</JSLink>
```

These changes break all my CSR and I have no idea how to fix it. I am aware that these two links have to be equivalent, although on the recreated subsite, browser tries to load the javascript from a domain of cdn.sharepointonline.com which is wrong. (I suspect this is due to wrong relative addressing).

All the help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. I am not sure what the problem was but I found the workaround that seems to work pretty good.

I scraped entirely the idea to use JSLink and instead I used `<SharePoint:ScriptLink>` tag and included the scripts that way. I wrapped my scripts so that they use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded([Script's closure here], 'clientForms.js');`
This seems to yield the same result as using JSLink, but the tokens in JSLink are not expanded to relative urls and links are not broken. The only downside is that no one is able to modify the scripts without the Sharepoint Designer as they are no more listed in JSLink field.